# Searching Multiple Webpages in PHP for a certain string

Tags: php, string, search

Okay, so basically, what I'm trying to do is search multiple webpages of the same website for a certain string, for instance my name.

The best way to exemplify this... Erm, suppose I have this google search with many pages of results, and I wanted to filter the results to where I can find the exact string I want, and parse that data onto something else.

So I want to search many pages of the same website looking for a specific string, so I an use some of the data that is also on that same page in something else.

I hope I explained it well enough, and thank you for your time!

Comment: so you want to programm a crawler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do the same thing with file_get_contents()

Example:

```
$html = file_get_contents(website_here);
if(stripos($html, $your_string_here){
    //Do what you'd like
}
```

stripos is case insensitive.  While it's possible to use other string options, after running a few speed tests (although I don't have the results anymore), stripos was quite fast and easy to implement.

Also, you can put all of this in a foreach clause so that you can cycle through all the websites that you have listed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to get more liberal hosting ... 100 requests is going to take in the reigon of 7-12 seconds on most 100mbps servers ...

When you've found a new host, ask the admin if they will install:

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

And then, you can thread in PHP, bring the time for your requests down to under a second on most 100mbps servers ...

Comment: With curl you can make multiple requests, with multiple threads you can have multiple requests being processed at once ... not the same ...